# Why do I get a warning from xml:lang attribute?

Tags: xhtml-1.0-strict, xhtml, aptana

Aptana gives me a warning saying "`<html>` has XML attribute xml:lang"
Here is the line. What's wrong here?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is fine, it's the bug of the built-in HTMLTidy validator

I've found the answer here:
https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/3034-templates

Answer (score 1):

What doctype have you used?

You should choose any xhtml valid doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

or

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

There is another one used for framesets...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using an XHTML doctype, such as

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
```

or

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

It could also be a problem with Aptana not properly recognizing the `xml:lang` attribute, but it is more likely that you are not using the correct DOCTYPE.